# Traffic from site like pu.gg, goo.gl?

Tags: traffic, hacking

Why is it that I get pageviews from sites like pu.gg, goo.gl? What does it mean? Am I visited by hackers? Is there any way to block this kind of page view from my analytics? I am kind'a alarm with this.

Comment: just wondering: couldn't you visit those urls and see what those sites are about?

Answer (score 4):

Goo.gl is a [URL shortener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening). It just means someone linked to your website using it. Pu.gg is a torrent tracker. I don't know why you would get pageviews from them. You may be hacked and hosting a torrent file. You should get your site out and look for any suspicious files.

Answer (score 0):

I know that Twitter automatically shortens URLs like t.co, could possibly be backlinks from Social Media sites like Google Plus, Google Analytics also offers URL shortener and uses Goo.gl